# How can I serve a static page, and also handle the routing? (Express)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a route that is my_domain.com/game. When a user requests that page, I want to serve them a static page from a folder. For that I could just do

```
app.use('/game', express.static('public/game'))
```

The issue is that I want that route to also accept queries, like /game?lobbyID=insert_id_here. So I went ahead and made it a route like this

```
app.use('/game', express.static('public/game'), (req, res, next) => {
    const id = req.query.lobbyID
    console.log(req.ip + " wants to connect to " + id)
})
```

Now it serves the page, but it doesn't do anything more than that. It never reaches the point where it can console log. I figured express.static must be stopping the routing, so I moved it like so

```
app.use('/game', (req, res, next) => {
    const id = req.query.lobbyID
    console.log(req.ip + " wants to connect to " + id)
    express.static('public/game')
})
```

Now it handles logging the IP and id perfectly, but the static files are not being shown. How can I make express co-operate and do both things?

Comment: try adding a separate route handling the parameters:
`app.get('/game',  (req, res) => {
    const id = req.query.lobbyID
    console.log(req.ip + " wants to connect to " + id)
})`
Not sure it will work, it may be worth trying though.

Comment: Does it work if you move express.static to after the anonymous function?app.use('/game', (req, res, next) => {
    const id = req.query.lobbyID
    console.log(req.ip + " wants to connect to " + id)
   next();
},  express.static('public/game'))

Comment: @Michele not work unfortunately. I've made a temporary fix though, which is having a deeper route (e.g /game/id_here), then after I've stored the ID, re-routing to just /game where I can serve the static files.

Comment: @CalIrvine Did unfortunately not work either.

Comment: What about use res.render or res.sendFile in the last example?